# Solving linear equation with LAPACKE

Tags: c, linear-algebra, lapack, lapacke

I'm trying to solve some linear equation (which is symmetrical, tridiagonal and positive). I have to use LAPACKE. My code is as follows:

```
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void print_mtrx(double * mtrx, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%f ", mtrx[i*m+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    double matrix[5*5] = {
        2,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  2,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  2,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  2,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  2
    };

    double rozw[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    double matrix2[5*5] = {
        7,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  7,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  7,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  7,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  7
    };



    LAPACKE_dptsv(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, 5, 5, matrix, matrix2, rozw, 5);

    print_mtrx(matrix, 5, 5);
    print_mtrx(matrix2, 5, 5);
    print_mtrx(rozw, 5, 1);

}
```

LAPACKE's function seems to do nothing, without any errors. The main problem is, I have no idea what do the function parameters stand for. I've searched long, but there is no real documentation. Here is what I managed to found or guess:

- int matrix_order -- LAPACK_COL_MAJOR or LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, how is matrix represented in memory
- lapack_int n -- size of matrix (i.e. number of columns)
- lapack_int nrhs -- not sure, maybe size of vector b
- double* d -- matrix of equations
- double* e -- no idea.
- double* b -- vector of solutions of equations from d
- lapack_int ldb -- leading direction of b (wherefore? is it not identical to nrhs, which itself is identical to n?)

How can I find real meaning of these arguments? How can I make my code work?

Comment: You have not checked the function return value. Here is the source code for `LAPACKE_dptsv()` http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/swiftnav/html/lapacke__dptsv_8c_source.html and here is the source code of `LAPACKE_dptsv_work()` which it calls http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/swiftnav/html/lapacke__dptsv__work_8c_source.html

Comment: @WeatherVane It returns 2, which tells me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to documentation for BLAS and/or LAPACK, [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl_11.2_ref) is probably the most comprehensive out there.  You can look up the docs for [?ptsv](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520989), which explains what each parameter is for.

(Hint: when searching for a BLAS or LAPACK in Google, be sure to drop the `s`/`d`/`c`/`z` prefix.)

Here's the relevant snippet:

> The routine solves for `X` the real or complex system of linear equations `A*X = B`, where `A` is an `n`-by-`n` symmetric/Hermitian positive-definite tridiagonal matrix, the columns of matrix `B` are individual right-hand sides, and the columns of `X` are the corresponding solutions.
>
> `A` is factored as `A = L*D*LT` (real flavors) or `A = L*D*LH` (complex flavors), and the factored form of `A` is then used to solve the system of equations `A*X = B`.
>
> #### Input Parameters
>
> `n`: The order of matrix `A`; `n ≥ 0`.
>
> `nrhs`: The number of right-hand sides, the number of columns in `B`; `nrhs ≥ 0`.
>
> `d`:  Array, dimension at least `max(1, n)`. Contains the diagonal elements of the tridiagonal matrix `A`.
>
> `e`, `b`: Arrays: `e(n - 1)`, `b(ldb,*)`. The array `e` contains the `(n - 1)` subdiagonal elements of `A`.  The array b contains the matrix `B` whose columns are the right-hand sides for the systems of equations. The second dimension of `b` must be at least `max(1,nrhs)`.
>
> `ldb`: The leading dimension of `b`; `ldb ≥ max(1, n)`.
>
> #### Output Parameters
>
> `d`: Overwritten by the `n` diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix `D` from the `L*D*LT` (real) / `L*D*LH` (complex) factorization of `A`.
>
> `e`: Overwritten by the `(n - 1)` subdiagonal elements of the unit bidiagonal factor `L` from the factorization of `A`.
>
> `b`: Overwritten by the solution matrix `X`.
>
> `info`: If `info = 0`, the execution is successful.  If `info = -i`, the `i`-th parameter had an illegal value.  If `info = i`, the leading minor of order `i` (and therefore the matrix `A` itself) is not positive-definite, and the solution has not been computed. The factorization has not been completed unless `i = n`.

Answer (score 2):

So one must to look into documentation of pure LAPACK (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/dea/dptsv_8f.html#af1bd4c731915bd8755a4da8086fd79a8), and also ignore incorrect (in case of LAPACKE) remark that LDB be greater or equal max(1,N).

The correct program is as follows:

```
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void print_mtrx(double * mtrx, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%f ", mtrx[i*m+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    double diagonal[5] = {5,1,5,1,5};
    double subdiagonal[4] = {0,0,0,0};

    double solution[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};


    LAPACKE_dptsv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 5 /*size of matrix*/, 1 /*number of columns in solution*/,
                  diagonal, subdiagonal, solution, 1 /*leading dimension of solution vector*/);

    print_mtrx(solution, 5, 1);
}
```